# Is it possible to automatically call a JS function after use header php function?

Tags: php, javascript, header

Is it possible to automatically call a JS function (or do any statement) after use header  php function (or click on any link) to redirect location ? And how to do that? Thanks you so much.

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Note: Normally, the JS function does'nt called,but when a special event happens, it called. Sr for my English :(

Answer (score 1):

If the PHP file which holds properly used header function redirect has any other HTML code, this HTML code will not be interpreted as it will never reach the browser. This is, by definition how header works and your PHP page isn't even supposed to send any output before header is called [by definition of the function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

One way to call a JS function that should ONLY execute if the visitor came to the page with this header redirect, would be to add a parameter to the page and on the destination page detect if the parameter is present.

For example. If the www.example1.com/original.php is the page that redirects to www.example2.com/redirect.php by using header, you could have header redirect to http://www.example2.com/redirect.php?redirected. In redirect.php you check if redirected parameter exists and if so you define a JS function and make it do what you want.

Comment: ok, thank u. I have a solution for this, but i'm trying to do different, another way, to find out the best solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In php you can do:

```
header("Location: http://mydomain.com/test.php");
```

Or print some JS to the page:

```
print "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = 'test.php';</script>";
```

Comment: The location header takes an absolute URI. You shouldn't give it a relative URI even if most browsers will silently error correct.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to automatically call a JS function (or do any statement) after use header php function to redirect location ?

Only by inserting a `<script>` element in the page being redirected to.

> (or click on any link)  to redirect location ?

You can bind an event handler to all the links on a given page. That will run when they are clicked (but before the browser leaves the page).

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make much sense. You're *either* redirecting *or* are outputting an HTML page with Javascript in it. Can't do both at the same time. You can output an HTML page with Javascript in it *after* the redirect has finished, i.e. on the next page you're redirecting to.